# For Einstein's equation $E= mc^2$ is it energy that increases or mass as the velocity increases?

Tags: special-relativity, mass-energy

I will be surprised if no one asked this before and I would be happy if it is answered already although I haven't located it just yet!

From Einstein's original paper "Does The Inertia of a Body Depend on it's Energy Content" 1905. I am wondering if maybe my original thinking is not right. I always thought that energy increased as velocity increased. End of story.

But as I hear videos and read books the mantra seems to be  mass increases as velocity increases. So which is right I wonder. I know I left gamma out of the equation in the question. Assume it is there thank you.

Comment: Try searching (using PSE’s search box) for “relativistic mass”. I got more than 3000 results.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is there a controversy on whether mass increases with speed?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133376/)

Comment: What is complicating the search and the heart of the problem  is that people may be including gamma in the  relativistic mass definition whereby relativistic mass does increase but mass does not. It would be the gamma term increasing as velocity increases and as a result the energy increases.

Comment: @G Smith right on the button ...that is the question I am asking . Thank you. I will read it

Comment: So this is a duplicate do you recommend I delete or how can I close it?

Comment: The invariant mass doesn’t increase. The energy and the relativistic mass do increase. They are proportional to each other, so there is no need for the concept of relativistic mass. (There are also reasons why it is conceptually a bad idea.)

Comment: Yes you are correct there is no confusion now I see it. I think when people are using the word mass they actually mean relativistic mass which includes the gamma and an invariant mass. Hopefully the call will close soon or I could delete it. Thank you for clearing this up for me

Comment: But when *physicists* talk about mass they mean *invariant mass*. Much of the pop-sci world still means relativistic mass; they are decades behind current best practice.

Comment: But the invariant mass of object does depend on it's energy content. A proton and a neutron together has more mass than a deuteron, forget about $\gamma$.

Comment: @JEJ I think you have it backwards a proton and an neutron together has less mass.Here is the link to backup what I say. If I am wrong let me know , I am trying to learn this material.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xo232kyTsO0&t=359s